# Keep website active while its loading the next page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I'm working on a website for a (german)Teamspeak server I made and I just noticed that when I click a link on my site it just shows a white page untill the content is fully loaded and ready to show.

Now my question is how does Youtube(and some other sites) work in that part? Youtube keeps showing the whole site after you clicked on something for example. There is just a small loading bar at the top but only main part of the site loads while the side-menu and the header just stay exactly as they were before.

Hope you understand what I mean (if not feel free to ask so I can try to explain it a bit better).

Website im working on (german): http://dissconnection.de/ 
If you click on something in the header you will see that it gets blank for a short moment and what I want is that the header stays where it is while loading.

(I think thats possible with frames but I dont want to use them too often and I think Youtube doesn't uses frames for that either).

Comment: YouTube makes heavy use of JavaScript to more closely create a "single page application" experience.  (Perhaps not entirely, but the concepts are very similar.)  They load a lot of content via AJAX instead of page loads.  Some use of frames is also certainly possible where appropriate.

Comment: You are going to want to lookup how to use Jquery and AJAX to start with. Then I would recommend looking into AngularJS after that. Those should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube and many other websites are using JavaScript frameworks in order to create '**Single Page Application**' type of sites.

This development technique allows you, as a developer, to specify which components you want to reload and which ones you don't really want to change (e.g. headers, footers, sidebars).

Take a look at how Angular 2 and React.js work.

You can still do something similar simply with Ajax but learning a JavaScript framework will help you out in a long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can do a lot using the TurboLinks framework
https://github.com/helthe/Turbolinks